# Contact Form 7 Pre-Check Radio button on-load

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm working on a `WordPress` site and I need a radio button on my contact form to be automatically checked on certain pages.

I am using the same contact form on all the pages.

Do I do this in `PHP` or `JavaScript` or are there any other options?

I know I can call an action on a certain page but how to write this... Thx!

So this is the CF7 code: 
And I want to select the last radio button and only it should be checked on a certain page

[radio class="123" subject "New Client|something@something.com" "Questions|something@something.com" "Looking for work|something@something.com"]

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, I dont particularly remember Contact Form 7 Code but yes you can do like this using Jquery

[Js Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/868048/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var get_selected_value = $('#selected_value').val();
    if(get_selected_value == 'yes')
    {
      $('#yes').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else if(get_selected_value == 'no')
    {
        $('#no').prop('checked', true);
    }
});

<div id="banner-message">
  <input type="hidden" name="selected_value" value="no" id="selected_value"/>
  Yes: <input type="radio" name="interested" id="yes" value="yes" />
  No: <input type="radio" name="interested" id="no" value="no" />
</div>
```

Here your selected value is stored in hidden variable, you can even use PHP directly in jquery instead of storing in hidden value.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll be implementing it shortly!